# How to open system activity and click button there?

Tags: android, android-activity, root

How an app like greenify, open system activity and click button there? The activity is "App Info", automatically clicked "Force Stop" button. and the app can click button in that activity **without root**.

Code to open activity "App Info" like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", "com.package.sendinput", null);
    intent.setData(uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Then the activity opened. To click button there, I have tried to execute adb shell input tap 200 340 (using same uid as my running app), but "Killed" by system. But using root can click the button.

Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: (guess work, because I haven't done something like this myself)

Greenify automation is done with running as Accessiblity service. In a nutshell, it retrieves current content of window and sends `AccessibilityEvent`s to specified views like: touch, focus.

Content window is described as `AccessibilityWindowInfo` which can be `TYPE_APPLICATION`,   `TYPE_INPUT_METHOD`, `TYPE_SYSTEM`.

For sending events to the window it uses `AccessibilityManager` to send `AccessibilityEvent` to the any child view you have retrieved in the `AccessibilityWindowInfo`

Reading: 
[UiAutomation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html)

[Accessibility package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/package-summary.html)

Comment: yes, but the app i mentioned (greenify) can do that without root :)

Comment: I never heard of the app, i just installed it, I can see that in non-root mode it runs as Accessibility service. With Accessibility API you can do this kind of automation. Sorry to say, I never used Accessibility APIs myself. I'd delete my answer as soon as someone posts new answer

Comment: do you have any example code for clicking using accessibility? thx

Answer (score 0):

You can start the App info activity for a particular application by package name by the following way

```
public void showAppDetailsActivity(String packageName) {
    final int sdkVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    if (sdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
    } else {

        final String appPkgName = "com.android.settings.ApplicationPkgName";

        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails");
        intent.putExtra(appPkgName, packageName);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: This is just opening the activity. how to click button there?